# Pagination path placeholder

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am looking for a way to be able to get page numbers from `hydra:view` elements from the response.

In my VueJS app, my table has a paginator at the bottom which represents all (or some pages) that can be navigated.

For example:

```
  "hydra:totalItems": 48,
  "hydra:view": {
    "@id": "/api/contracts?page=1",
    "@type": "hydra:PartialCollectionView",
    "hydra:first": "/api/contracts?page=1",
    "hydra:last": "/api/contracts?page=5",
    "hydra:next": "/api/contracts?page=2"
  }
```

Given the data above, I need to build a paginator that includes all the pages (1,2,3,4 and 5). When the number of items goes up, I would stop generating the page button after some number of adjacent pages.

Is there any way for ApiPlatform to return path with placeholder (e.g. `/api/contract?page={{ page }}`) so I could plug in all necesarry params AND page?

Comment: I think you can try to decorate `PartialCollectionViewNormalizer` service.

Comment: @shvv That was a way to do that, thanks! Can you please submit as an answer so I could accept it? :)

Comment: Done. Maybe you can share some code with future readers...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to decorate `PartialCollectionViewNormalizer` service.